# Mysql query turns non-affected to 0

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a simple query that when executed updates the cash available by some users when their loans are due:

```
$sqlx = "UPDATE competitions
    SET cash = (SELECT cash_after_deduct 
                FROM (SELECT l.competitions_id, 
                             (c.cash-l.due_amount) AS cash_after_deduct
                      FROM loans l
                      JOIN competitions c ON l.competitions_id = c.id
                      WHERE l.due_date='2018-10-28'
                      GROUP BY l.competitions_id) q1
                WHERE q1.competitions_id = competitions.id
    )
";
```

The cash row of those users with a loan due on `2018-10-28` should be modified. And it works; however the cash row in users with different due dates are reset to 0,  while they should remain unaffected.

Any idea on what can be wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You are updating **all** rows. You need to add a condition or check if the result of the sub-query is not equal to 0 and use the existing `cash` value if it is.

Comment: What is the aggregate function used for the `GROUP BY`? It looks like `due_amount` but unless you specify an aggregate function, [MySQL can pick any random value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) from the grouped column data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` query has no criteria to limit the scope of the update to only those affected by the `due_date`.

Additionally since you are not using an aggregate function on the loans table, MySQL is free to choose ANY single value from those that were grouped. This can lead to unexpected results.

To resolve the issue you can change the `SET` subquery to a `JOIN`. This will prevent unmatched records from the loans table from updating the competitions table with 0's. As well as reduce the number of queries that would need to occur, since using a subquery in the `SET` would require a query to be issued for each record in order to match the current row in competitions that is being updated by set.

### Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a2c147/1

```
UPDATE competitions AS c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT l.competitions_id, SUM(l.due_amount) AS total_due
    FROM loans AS l
    WHERE l.due_date = '2018-10-28'     
    GROUP BY l.competitions_id
    #optionally limit scope to those that have an amount due
    #HAVING total_due > 0
) AS d
ON d.competitions_id = c.id
SET c.cash = c.cash - d.total_due
```

**Data Set**

```
competitions
---
| id  | cash | 
|-----|------| 
| 1   | 5.00 | 
| 2   | 2.00 | 
| 3   | 0.00 |
```

```
loans
---
| id | competitions_id | due_amount |   due_date | 
|----|-----------------|------------|------------| 
| 1  |               1 |       1.00 | 2018-10-19 | 
| 2  |               1 |       1.00 | 2018-10-28 | 
| 3  |               2 |       1.00 | 2018-10-28 | 
| 4  |               1 |       1.00 | 2018-10-28 | 
| 5  |               3 |       1.00 | 2018-11-19 |
```

### Result

```
| id | cash | total_due | cash_after_deduction | loan_deductions |
|----|------|-----------|----------------------|-----------------|
|  1 |    5 |         2 |                    3 |               2 |
|  2 |    2 |         1 |                    1 |               1 |
```

This works by first retrieving the `competitions_id` and `due_amount` values from the loans table that are affected by the `due_date`.

The base `competitions` table updates are then limited by the `INNER JOIN`, which includes only the records that match those found within the loans table.

I used `SUM` as the aggregate function to ensure all of the `due_amount` records from all the loans for the competitions_id are totaled. 
This looks like what you had intended, if not and you want a single `due_amount`, the query can be modified to match your desired results.